Can't compile C HelloWorld
I'm trying to get stated with programmming in C, but when I try to compile "HelloWorld" to run I get a (.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'error. Edit: I am using wsl.
Ubuntu window:
dodojesu@DumbshitsINC:\~$ dir
hello.c  hello.c.save
dodojesu@DumbshitsINC:\~$ gcc hello.c -o hello
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function \`\_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to \`main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
dodojesu@DumbshitsINC:\~$

This is the hello world file:
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}

I've tried fixing it with the MS tutorials etc. but none of what I've found addresses this problem
Edit:
dodojesu@DumbshitsINC:\~$ gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0

Edit:
ld --version

GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42


According to your comment on the Staging Ground, the output of cat hello.c is empty, which means the file is actually empty. The file you showed above might be a different one or is unsaved.

gcc and an external stand alone editor is a tough way to get into programming in C. It is an unforgiving development environment not really suited to beginners.

Unrelated: // printf() displays the string inside quotation is a bad comment in several ways. 1) is not true 2) adds clutter to the code 3) is not true 4) is redundant even for beginner programmers 5) is not true

Try each compilation phase on its own: gcc -E for preprocessing; gcc -S for translation to assembly; gcc -c for creation of object file with no linking.

By any chance, were you using nano? The existence of the save file could mean that the file was not correctly saved.

It would be the best if you attached the hello.c file you're trying to compile.

The reason of undefined reference to 'main' error is that compiler can't find int main() function in your file. I have two suggestions of why this would happened.

The hello.c have an unusual encoding (e.g. UTF16) and gcc fail to read it properly. Please use code editing tools, like VS Code or Emacs, to properly encode your files.
hello.c have not been saved with the content you believe. Check the file with type hello.c on cmd or cat hello.c on powershell.


The Error clearly says that undefined reference to \`main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
which means main was not defined in your hello.c and retuned 1 to the operating system
